# Why does my AlarmManager trigger instantly?

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager

I want the AlarmManager to repeat a task at scheduled time (weekly)

I used the following code:

```
for (Integer day : daysList) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, PersonalUtils.getDigitalWeek(day));
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, task.getHour());
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, task.getMinute());
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    intent.putExtra("id", task.getId());
    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(), requestCode, intent, 0);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, operation);
}
```

However the alarm it triggered prematurely.

**For example**: Assuming that it is 18:30 Wed now. I setup a task which should be triggered at 17:30 Tue next week but instead the alarm is triggered immediately

Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: Can you check c.getTime() after you set everything, I think there is some miscalculation. You may need to setTime() for next week on Calendar first and then use.

Comment: If you set a date which already has been passed the alarm will trigger immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do an inexact alarm, which only allows for a few specific constants, `INTERVAL_DAY`, `INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES`, etc. See [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for more. Those constants are only supposed to be used for InexactRepeatingAlarms, but I see your doing a RepeatingAlarm.

You have a couple of choices, you can either set the alarm to trigger in exactly 1 week, or you can set it to trigger every day inexactly and only pay attention to it if the alarm occurs during the 7th day. To trigger exactly every 7 days from now, try this:

```
final long WEEK_IN_MILLIS= 604800000;
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis()+WEEK_IN_MILLIS,
            WEEK_IN_MILLIS, operation);
```

Note that I set it to first trigger in 1 week, then repeat every week after that. That should work for you.